# ¿Cómo especificar dónde guardar mi archivo .log en Log4j.properties?

Tags: java, neo4j

Estoy intentando obtener los archivos .logs de mi aplicación en Java para ver por qué y dónde salen mis errores, pero no consigo ver dónde esta la ruta para guardar mi archivo "mylogfile.log" en mi código de log4j.properties:

```
#log4j.rootCategory=A1, FILE
#log4j.rootCategory=A1, FILE

#LOGGER CONFIG
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

#FIRST APPENDER - TO STDOUT
# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
#log4j.appender.A1.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.Threshold=DEBUG
#log4j.appender.CON\u000eSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-22d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:ms} %-8p %c [%t] - %m (%l)%n
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-13d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}%-4p[%t](%F:%L)-%m %n


log4j.appender.A1.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.file.file=mylogfile.log
log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize=10KB
log4j.appender.A1.file.append=false
log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex=2

log4j.appender.A1.file.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.A1.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c: %m%n
```

¿Dónde puede encontrarlo? ¿O cómo es la sintaxis para especificar una ruta a guardar mi archivo .log?

Answer (score 1):

Tras leer muchos libros de log4j encontré la solución.

El código debe quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
#log4j.rootCategory=A1

#LOGGER CONFIG
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1


#set file text
log4j.appender.A1 = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File = D:\ruta\a\mi\Log.log
log4j.appender.A1.maxFileSize = 20MB
log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Y listo, el archivo queda en la carpeta donde la especifique, nunca nadie me sugirió usar `RollingFileAppender` para llamar mis funciones.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que establecerla en la propiedad

> log4j.appender.A1.file.File

Por ejemplo:

```
log4j.appender.A1.file.File=D:\\traza.log
```

Comment: Me Da: log4j:WARN No such property [file] in org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender.

Comment: Quita el primer file: log4j.appender.A1.File=D:\traza.log (y también el de las demás líneas en las que aparece)

Comment: Ya no me aparece el error pero aun sigue sin aparecerme mi archivo .log en mi carpeta, ¿es un error mio?, (Ya modifique el codigo).

Comment: Has conservado esta línea?: log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender